# Checking absence of attribute with cts:query

Tags: xquery, marklogic, cts-search

I have an XML fragment where I want to have different queries based in the existence of the id attribute:

```
<author order="1" 
        id="99999999" 
        initials="A." 
        given-names="Able" 
        surname="Baker" 
        fullname="Able Baker"/>
```

I have tried:

```
let $first-query := if ($first)
                then cts:or-query((
                    cts:element-attribute-word-match(xs:QName("author"), xs:QName("given-names"), $first || "*", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint")),
                    cts:element-attribute-word-match(xs:QName("author"), xs:QName("initials"), $first || "*", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"))
                     ))
                else ()

let $last-query := if ($last)
               then cts:element-attribute-word-match(xs:QName("author"), xs:QName("surname"), $last || "*", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"))
               else ()

let $author-no-id-query := 
    cts:and-query((
        cts:not-query(
            cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("author"), xs:QName("id"), "*")
        ),
        $first-query,
        $last-query
    ))

let $query :=    cts:element-query(xs:QName("author"),
                 cts:or-query(($author-no-id-query, $author-id-query
                    )))
```

If the id exists, then a different query takes place and a match against the id occurs.  How do I detect an absence of an attribute in MarkLogic?

Comment: You could try to specify "wildcarded" as option for the `cts:element-attribute-value-query`, because according to the [docs](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-attribute-value-query) wildcarded is only automatically enabled when a wildcard index is enabled. But I have no idea if this will yield correct results when doing unfiltered searches(or otherwise only using lexicon functions). Another option would be to never remove an attribute but leave it in with an empty string. Far from pretty but that does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have inserted two test documents into the database:

```
xdmp:document-insert('/example.xml', <author order="1"
        id="99999999"
        initials="A." 
        given-names="Able" 
        surname="Baker" 
        fullname="Able Baker"/>)

xdmp:document-insert('/example2.xml', <author order="1" 
        initials="A." 
        given-names="Able" 
        surname="Baker" 
        fullname="Able Baker"/>)
```

And run the following query against these documents:

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),
cts:element-query(xs:QName('author'), cts:and-query((
  cts:not-query(cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('author'), xs:QName('id'), '*', ("wildcarded")))
 )
)))
```

This search only matches the document where the ID attribute does not exist.

Comment: I think you don't really need the `cts:element-query`, because the `cts:element-attribute-value-query` already specifies the `author` element anyway